# Modulo operation on primary key column is too slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a table with tens of millions records in SQL Server 2008.
First column (ID) is the primary key. Other columns are not index-able.

It is required to list all records whose IDs are multiple of 30. So I wrote:

```
SELECT ID,... FROM table1 WHERE (ID between value1 AND value2) AND (ID % 30 = 0)
```

This query is *too* slow, even when the result includes only 100 records.
Therefore, my database is of no use unless I find a faster solution.

Special features of my DB are:

1. I never UPDATE values in this table. Only INSERT and SELECT.
2. ID of each new record (INSERT) is more than all previous existing IDs in the table. (IDs come in ascending order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have at your disposal are indexes. So you must express the problem in terms of B-Trees, key order, and ranges. To reduce the execution time you must reduce the range of rows scanned by the query. There are couple of possible approaches:

- [Filtered indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx). You can create a filtered index on `ID` for the predicate `ID % 30 = 0` and include the projected columns. This will work *only* for `WHERE ID % 30 = 0`
- [Persisted Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You can created a persisted computed column for `ID % 30` and add it as the leftmost key in the clustered index (dues to low selectivity). This will work for `WHERE ID % 30 =0` but also for `WHERE ID % 30 = 1` or `WHERE ID % 30 = 29` for instance. But will not work for `WHERE ID % 29=0`.

As you see the options are not really that great. The requirement is very unusual and I actually doubt it comes form a serious business requirement, it seems more like an artifact of a chosen implementation for a more generic requirement. If you would state your business requirement, we could probably offer a better solution.

Comment: Dear Remus, My application INSERTs some input values each second to this table. ID is in fact a time value (total seconds passed since first moment of year 2000). Other columns are input values. By the above query I wanted to find input values for every half-minute.

Comment: How about save the relevant entries into separate table(s), for every 30s, 10 min or whatever? Pre-aggregation is a well known technique.

Comment: If value2 and value1 are not too far apart, you could compute all the possible numbers between them that are divisble by 30. Then, you could use a query that says WHERE ID in (n1, n2, n3, n4... etc)

Comment: there maybe about 1K items that are divisible by 30, between value1 and value2. by the way Darius' solution seems to be the most applicable technique till now.

Comment: this table cannot be pre-aggregated, because sometime we have to select records whose ID % 240 = 0, sometimes ID % 1200 = 0, etc! maybe the SQL Server is not suitable for my application at all !!?

Comment: U preaggregate for 10 min, for one hour etc separately

Comment: You can use Darius' idea and extend it by joining against a table of numbers. But too many seeks and the query will revert to scan.